# Salvar nova posição de células após reordenadas e afetar o model (datasource)

Tags: ios, objective-c, tabela-html

Estou precisando da implementação de uma tableview, onde eu possa reordenar a posição das células e que elas fiquem salvas na nova ordem. E essa nova ordem deve afetar a ordem que elas ficam salvas também o model (no caso um NSMutableArray ou NSMutableDictionry).

Colocarei imagem abaixo para ilustrar melhor:

[image: Posição Inicial]

[image: Modo de Edição]

[image: Mudança na Ordem das Células]

[image: Nova ordem que preciso salvar]

Answer (score 1):

Na `@interface` que implementa o `UITableViewDataSource (geralmente o`*view controller* associado à tabela), você precisa implementar o *selector* [`tableView:moveRowAtIndexPath:toIndexPath:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDataSource_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITableViewDataSource/tableView:moveRowAtIndexPath:toIndexPath:). Na implementação você precisa trocar a ordem dos elementos do seu `NSMutableArray`, como no exemplo abaixo:

```
- (void)   tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
  moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)sourceIndexPath
         toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)destinationIndexPath
{
    NSInteger fromIndex = sourceIndexPath.row;
    NSInteger toIndex = destinationIndexPath.row;
    if (fromIndex == toIndex) return;

    id item = [self.items objectAtIndex:fromIndex];
    [self.items removeObjectAtIndex:fromIndex];
    [self.items insertObject:item atIndex:toIndex];
}
```

Comment: Carlos eubtentei algo parecido com oq vc apresentou. Mas vou testar a seu codigo e relatar o resultado!